# Parsing JSON with AJAX - show random item of the JSON and update after an amount of time

Tags: ajax, xml, json, parsing

I'm able to parse JSON with ajax, but at the moment it shows all the names out of the JSON.

I want only one name viewed and after an amount of time I want another one viewed and so on..

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    parseJson();
});

function parseJson(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'data/members.json',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            succes(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            window.alert("error");
        }
    });
};

function succes(dataObj){
    var counter = 1;
    $.each(dataObj.Members.Member, function(indexData, valueData){
        var htmlString = "";
        htmlString += '<article class="memberInfo" data-object="' + counter + '">';
        htmlString += "<div class=''><p>" + valueData.Firstname + ' ' + valueData.Surname + "</p></div>";
        htmlString += "</article>";
        $("#members").append(htmlString);
        counter++;      
    });
}
```

Comment: Save `data` in a global variable, and use `setInterval` to run a function periodically that selects a random element from the array and displays it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `.append` you can use `.html` and set a staggering timeout so that it cycles through the names that get displayed:

```
var timer = 0;
$.each(...
    setTimeout(function () {
        var htmlString = "";
        /* snip */
        $("#members").html(htmlString);
    }, timer + (indexData * 2000));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills